# SQL Server query that display tables names which contains specific column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to write a query in SQL Server to find all table names in a database that have a column name like for example `phone_number`? I want to display table name and all phone numbers in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the tables with that name doing a simple query:

```
select table_name
from information_schema.columns
where column_name = 'phone_number';
```

You need some form of dynamic SQL to actually get the phone numbers.  My recommendation would be to generate the SQL using a statement such as:

```
select replace(replace('select ''[table_name]'' as which, [column_name] from [table_name] union all', '[table_name]', table_name), '[column_name]', column_name)
from information_schema.columns
where column_name = 'phone_number';
```

Then copy this into SMSS, remove the final `union all` and run the query.  I *know* that this version assumes that you have reasonable identifiers for the table name.  The logic can be enhanced to quote the identifier if that is actually needed.

You can also fully automate the process using dynamic SQL or `sp_MSforeachtable`.

Comment: I want to use dynamic SQL to automate the query but I don't know how connect tables names with phone_number.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code:

```
SELECT sys.columns.name AS ColumnName,sys.tables.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns JOIN sys.tables ON
sys.columns.object_id = sys.tables.object_id
WHERE sys.columns.name = 'phone_number'
```